# Got ambiguous match error while trying to count number of element that exist on the page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to count how many the star is selected based on this HTML

```
<div class="c-fld">
  <ul class="js-review-star c-rating">
    <li data-value="1" title="Very Bad product" class="c-rating__unit is-selected">
      <span class="c-rating__icon c-icon c-icon--star c-icon--large"></span></li>
    <li data-value="2" title="Bad product" class="c-rating__unit is-selected">
      <span class="c-rating__icon c-icon c-icon--star c-icon--large"></span></li>
    <li data-value="3" title="Average" class="c-rating__unit is-selected">
      <span class="c-rating__icon c-icon c-icon--star c-icon--large"></span></li>
    <li data-value="4" title="Good stuff!" class="c-rating__unit">
      <span class="c-rating__icon c-icon c-icon--star c-icon--large"></span></li>
    <li data-value="5" title="I love it!" class="c-rating__unit">
      <span class="c-rating__icon c-icon c-icon--star c-icon--large"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

From that, I use this method:

```
def change_review_rating
  @count = page.all('.c-rating__unit.is-selected').count
  puts = "number of element: #{@count}"
end
```

I also tried using another form of selector like these:

CSS

`.c-rating .is-selected`

XPATH

`//li[contains(@class, 'is-selected')]`

but all of them is returning `Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching xpath/css (Capybara::Ambiguous)`. I know there are 3 elements matching, that's why I need the code to count it. Can you help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Capybaras `all` method can't raise `Capybara::Ambiguous` so either that's not where the error is coming from or something/someone has redefined `all`.  Add the stacktrace you get with the error to your question.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, the stacktrace does not helping at all. It just shows the file that I wrote from the .feature file to the object_abstractions (where I define the change_review_rating). I looked at the rubydoc for `all` definition but I can't find `ib/capybara/node/finders.rb` file on my ruby file :(

Comment: Then add `puts` to your code at different places to figure out where the error is actually coming from - the only place that raises Ambiguous is https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb#L303 - which is only called from `find`, `ancestor`, and `sibling` - it's not called by `all` - so the code you're showing is not where that error is coming from